# Powershell delete duplicate line has start same of other

Tags: string, powershell, file, duplicates

in powershell i would like delete duplicate line in txt file when they start similar :

```
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_00.jpg?Watchout=1588338564&User=oj-e39DOyiUJCjtG3E2DWaeT8Q8_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_01.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=EjHBJ-biGSlM-ewPMVs_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_01.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=EjHBJ-biGSlM-ewPMVs_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_01.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=EjHBJ-biGSlM-ewPMVs_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_02.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=IPElkKyuulUYY1AL~~y4Y-HedKarGntAexw14_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_02.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=IPElkKyuulUYY1AL~~y4Y-HedKarGntAexw14_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_02.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=IPElkKyuulUYY1AL~~y4Y-HedKarGntAexw14_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_02_00.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=VIybnoLd8cthJ7MfsFM6EfD3M_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
```

Should becoming in my txt file :

```
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_00.jpg?Watchout=1588338564&User=oj-e39DOyiUJCjtG3E2DWaeT8Q8_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_01.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=EjHBJ-biGSlM-ewPMVs_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_02.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=IPElkKyuulUYY1AL~~y4Y-HedKarGntAexw14_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_02_00.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=VIybnoLd8cthJ7MfsFM6EfD3M_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
```

Because i count 3 times :  *https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_01.jpg* , i need only one time every jpg file : 9999_01_00.jpg

how can i make that ? delete duplicate line is not very hard but when line are not exacly similar it is a little bit more difficult !

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing that would be:

```
$newText = Get-Content -Path 'X:\FileWithUrls.txt' |
            Group-Object @{Expression = { ($_ -split '\?')[0]}} | 
            ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] }

# output on screen
$newText

# output to new text file
$newText | Set-Content -Path 'X:\DeDupedFileWithUrls.txt' -Force
```

Output:

```
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_00.jpg?Watchout=1588338564&User=oj-e39DOyiUJCjtG3E2DWaeT8Q8_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_01.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=EjHBJ-biGSlM-ewPMVs_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_01_02.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=IPElkKyuulUYY1AL~~y4Y-HedKarGntAexw14_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
https://mysite.local/9999/9999_02_00.jpg?Watchout=1182344561&User=VIybnoLd8cthJ7MfsFM6EfD3M_&dominus=3PK5GF6789
```

---

**Small explanation:**

The `Group-Object` groups similar lines from the text file together.
This is based on a property we provide and in this case, it is the part of the string **before** the `?`.

To get that, we simply split the string on the question mark and only use the first part `[0]`.

*<sup>because `-split` uses regex, we need to escape that with `\?`</sup>*

This is wrapped inside a calculated (on-the-fly) property with `@{Expression = { ($_ -split '\?')[0]}}`

Next we loop through the groups and output only the first item of each group

Comment: it works wonderfully i will try to understand the solution thank you very much
can you explain how this part work ?

`Group-Object @{Expression = { ($_ -split '\?')[0]}} | 
            ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] }`

Comment: @VeilleurTryToFix I have added some explanation for you.